# Sci-Fi poem in iambic pentameter about a little person who became normal size within days involving Elvis Presley

Tags: story-identification, dreams, poetry

OK experts, here goes nothing. On my 14th birthday (just over 33 years ago) I was visiting the school library and I picked up a book of poems. While I do not remember the author (the book was an anthology of sorts), I distinctly remember one of the excerpts from the book being a relatively lengthy poem written in iambic pentameter - perhaps limerick form. The poem outlined the life of a little person who, after taking a magic elixir, became normal size within days. Over time however, he grew and grew and was eventually one of the tallest people on Earth. He eventually fell into a deep depression for being abnormal again and was visited by none other than the reincarnated version of Elvis Presley singing "The Wonder of You". Immediately after this scene, the man overdosed on barbiturates and committed suicide... however in reality he awoke from a dream and realized that none of the events in the work actually transpired. The mystery of it all was that there was a live recording of Elvis performing the song on his nightstand. Does this ring any bells?

Comment: It doesn't ring any bells, but now I have [Empire State Human](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do8F5lU1TiI) in my head.